# "Trying to unpickle estimator LinearRegression from version X when using version Y" - But I have only the Y version on my .venv, what takes?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The exact warning is
`....\.venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:329: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LinearRegression from version 0.24.1 when using version 1.0.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.`

I saw several questions on this matter here and on other forums - they all sum up in uninstall and install the latter version.

I tried that, but still getting the error. Moreover, the model building and the consumer are on the same VSCode worksapce using the same .venv which holds `scikit-learn==1.0.2` - so where does the 0.24.1 come from and more important, how can I solve this warning and be sure my predictions are true?

EDIT per @rickhg12hs request:

the code part is very basic:

```
self.ModelHeight = pickle.load(open(filePath, "rb")
```

Comment: Would you show the lines of code that generate the warning ... and any other warning messages?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, sure, I updated the post with some code. No other warnings appear but the one mentioned above.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, sorry for the above, just run the code again - indeed no other warning messages appear, but, it looks like this (like not all message is printed): ```[full path]\.venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:329: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LinearRegression from version 0.24.1 when using version 1.0.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
  warnings.warn(```

Comment: If you look at the output of `python -m pickletools filepath`, what value do you see for `_sklearn_version`?  If it's really `0.24.1`, then that must be the version that created it.  I would investigate the model creation more, with something like `pickletools.dis(pickle.dumps(your_model))` right after you create it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Your case

I think (or maybe am pretty sure) that it's about the version of `sklearn` with which your pickle model was **created**-- that mismatches the `sklearn` version with which you are **loading** the model.

In your case

```
pip install scikit-learn==1.0.2
```

should do the trick.

---

#### My case

In my case, I *tried to resolve* the following warning message

```
/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:334: 
UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LinearRegression from version 1.1.1 
when using version 0.23.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. 
Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
```

with

```
pip install scikit-learn==1.1.1
```

but the [documentation of the version](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v1.1.html) says :

```
Version 1.1.0 of scikit-learn requires python 3.8+, ...
```

whereas I am running `python 3.7` !

---

#### Caveat

Hopefully your conflict with version 1.0.1 should be solved, as [its documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v1.0.html) says :

```
Version 1.0.0 of scikit-learn requires python 3.7+, ...
```

though **other dependencies** on your existing version (0.24.1) of `scikit-learn` is not guaranteed here !